# Override methods generated by Xamarin Java Binding

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

When using Xamarin to create a Java Bindings project so that Android Java jars may be referenced through C#, how would one go about overriding the generated C# only?

I am encountering an error post binding generation that seems as though it is easily fixed by using an explicit cast instead of the generated use of the JavaCast utility.  I am not sure how I can go about telling the Xamarin binding generator to skip this method generation without excluding it entirely.

I have tried including the overridden methods in the Library Binding Project in both the Additions folder, and in the general project, but the error I am receiving when I do that indicates that that type already defines a member with the same parameter types, so it is recognizing it, but not before the bindings are generated.

I realize that I could generate the bindings once, make the modifications to the generated files and try and ensure that the Library Binding Project is never built again, but I would like to avoid that upkeep cost, or the check in of generated files. This is a complete last resort work around.

Java code:

```
public interface IUpdateListener<T> {
    public void onUpdate(T data);
}
```

...

```
// This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated x.y.z.IUpdateListener
private class UpdateListener implements IUpdateListener<byte[]> {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(byte[] data) {
       //Does some stuff
    }
}
```

Resulting Xamarin generated C# code:

```
void global::x.y.z.IUpdateListener.OnUpdate (global::Java.Lang.Object p0)
{
    // This line has an error with the call to JavaCast
    OnUpdate (global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<byte[]>(p0));
}
```

Error on Generated line:

`Error  362 The type 'byte[]' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<TResult>(Android.Runtime.IJavaObject)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'byte[]' to 'Android.Runtime.IJavaObject'.`

Caveat - We are consuming the jars, not producing them, so I cannot change the Java code at all.

Thank you for your help!

Update 11/10:
The issue I was encountering was confirmed a bug buy Xamarin and can be found here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24312

The work around I was given https://gist.github.com/rob-derosa/61429e8967faf263e635#file-gistfile1-xml

When I add the work around to my metadata file, I get a more manageable error stating that those classes which update with a byte[] implementations `does not implement interface member 'foo.bar.IUpdateListener.OnUpdate(Java.Lang.Object)'`, which is fairly expected as they do not.

I was then able to create partial classes in the additions folder which implement the `OnUpdate(Java.Lang.Object)` method, and perform the explicit cast, and call into the generated OnUpdate from the actual code.  This method has no errors or warnings.

I suppose there really isn't a good way to perform an actual override of generated code, but I was able to work around the issue prompting the original question.